# Move display line with Ctrl-E in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, gvim

I've set `noremap j gj` and `k gk` in gVim for particular filetypes, to make Vim move by display lines rather than "actual" lines during navigation. However, I also frequently use the Ctrl-E shortcut to scroll through the buffer without changing cursor position, and I don't know how to make that scroll a display line only. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. (With `:set wrap`,) Vim will always scroll by entire physical lines (also when scrolling via the scrollbar). I guess this is a limitation of the implementation.